# Como hacer un contador de manera recursiva?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito hacer un función recursiva que me cuente desde 1 hasta un número introducido por el usuario.

Tengo esto:

```
def contador(num):
    #caso base
    if num == 1:
        return num
    else:
        return contador(num)

num=int(input("Hasta que número quieres llegar ?"))

print (contador(num))
```

Comment: Te comento que Python tiene por defecto un nivel de recursividad acotado por defecto en 1000 recursiones (eventualmente se puede ampliar pero siempre  hay un limite). Si pides contar hasta 1001 con cualquier función recursiva  tendrás un error.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código lo único que hacía falta realmente era decrementar el contador en la llamada recursiva contador(num-1), e imprimir al inicio de la función.

```
def contador(num):
     print(num)
     if num == 1:
        return
     else:
        return contador(num-1)

num=int(input("Hasta que numero quieres llegar ?"))    
contador(num)
```

Comment: Hola miimote, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Aunque ese código puede servir para resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de detalle: ¿cómo funciona?¿por qué resuelve el problema? Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.

Answer (score 1):

Me gusta complicarme un poco la lógica, espero te sea de ayuda.

```
def contador(num, lista=[], cont=0):
  cont+=1
  lista.append(cont)
  if cont < num:
    return  contador(num, lista, cont) 
  else:
    return lista
num=int(input("Hasta que número quieres llegar ?"))
print(contador(numm))
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu código puedes realizar una función recursiva para imprimir el numero de elementos que solicitas de esta forma:

```
def contador(num, count=0):
    #caso base
    print count
    if num == 0:
        return "Termina conteo en: %s" % count
    return contador(num-1, count+1)

num=int(input("Hasta que numero quieres llegar?"))

print (contador(num))
```

Agrego una [**demo en linea**](https://repl.it/@Jorgesys/BossyHonoredHammerheadbird).

Comment: Hola Jorgesys, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Aunque ese código puede servir para resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, sería ideal que añadieras algo más de detalle: ¿cómo funciona?¿por qué resuelve el problema? Lee [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) para más información y consejos.

Comment: Tu como siempre asignando negativos a mis respuestas y las demás aunque sean malas respuestas o aún ediciones  del OP asignas +1 , es una forma un poco enferma de seguir mi trabajo en el sitio, además afectas a la comunidad tratando de dar respuestas incorrectas a los usuarios. Si no conoces la tecnología en cuestion lo mejor es omititr. **Al menos en esta ocasión agregaste un comentario.**, Saludos.